# Can I retrieve physical/unmanaged information of .Net (C#) managed object

Tags: c#, .net

I am learning .NET/C# and because I almost always want to find out how managed object represent in real memory, I am wondering if there is any programmatic method to get these information, including object memory address, size in byte, memory layout and so on?

I know that .NET discourage it and hide information as internal implementation detail. But I am really curious about it for debugging and learning purpose.

Comment: If you step through a disassembled version of the application, using the C# byte code then you can see see what is going on, but to get more information you will need to go lower-level, C# won't give you the ability to look too low-level, C++ becomes your only option, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 compiled versions of the code that is produced the C# compiler:

- First, it is compiled into Common Intermediary Language (CIL). You can look at this by using the `ildasm` command in a Visual Studio Command Prompt or by using a (better) tool like [Redgate's .NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)
- It is then compiled from CIL to native machine code (by the Just In Time Compiler) and run. You can view this code by going `Debug > Windows > Disassembly` in Visual Studio.

But you are interested in the memory representation of the native types. This may be difficult and hard to grasp, but if you feel like you're up to it you can use `WinDbg` and `SOS.dll` to debug Managed Code in a native way. I would look at [this list of links](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rextang/archive/2007/07/24/4026494.aspx) to get you started. Just google "SOS.dll" for more information.

I don't think you will be able to (easily) do this programatically at all from the CLR. Maybe (big maybe) if you used NGEN to compile your assemblies ahead-of-time then use some sneaky C or C++ you might be able to do this, but it would be *extremely* hard (this is out of my knowledge zone, someone who works on the JIT team might be able to help you)

Comment: thanks for your information. It doesn't seem to have straight ways in C# itself. I will give up. I can view raw memory content in disassembly but can't view managed memory content from CIL. But anyway...

Comment: Link to "list of links" is broken.